# Why I can not successfully installed the RubyGem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Dear Stack Overflow readers,

I am having a problem about install the RubyGem. I have tried two ways to install it, but all failed.

Firstly, I run the `sudo command gem install github-pages`.
The output as below:

```r
dhcp-128-189-232-78:Repos 7Ymr$ sudo gem install github-pages
Password:
Fetching: public_suffix-2.0.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed public_suffix-2.0.5
Fetching: addressable-2.5.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed addressable-2.5.2
Fetching: colorator-1.1.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed colorator-1.1.0
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.10.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.10.2
Fetching: ffi-1.9.18.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.18
Fetching: rb-inotify-0.9.10.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-inotify-0.9.10
Fetching: sass-listen-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sass-listen-4.0.0
Fetching: sass-3.5.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sass-3.5.1
Fetching: jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.0
Fetching: listen-3.0.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed listen-3.0.6
Fetching: jekyll-watch-1.5.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-watch-1.5.0
Fetching: kramdown-1.13.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed kramdown-1.13.2
Fetching: liquid-4.0.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing github-pages:
    liquid requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
#>                               ^
```

And then, I also try to download and install from rubygems website. I download the latest version and run the install command, but also have some error.

```r
dhcp-128-189-232-78:downloads 7Ymr$ cd rubygems-2.6.13/
dhcp-128-189-232-78:rubygems-2.6.13 7Ymr$ ruby setup.rb
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems
#>                                   ^                              ^
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Wanted to know what would be the best way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The errors are both very clear. In the first case, your Ruby version is too old for the version of liquid that needs to be installed. Run `ruby --version` to find out what version of Ruby your system is using as default. You will need to update to Ruby 2.1.0 or later to install `liquid`, which is a required dependency of the `github-pages`gem you are trying to install.

In the second case, Ruby did not have permission to write into the folder. "Permission denied" errors almost always mean you forgot to run the command with administrative permissions. In this instance, you should have run `sudo ruby setup.rb`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I really appreciate the quick answer~